# Temporarily disabling Heroku accounts plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ssh, rake, accounts

I have searched for a difinitive answer, but can't find one anywhere.

I created an SSH key for my app under one heroku account. It places the SSH in the default place. Everything was great, until I started using a second Heroku account, where I started using the ddollar accounts plugin. Great, it allows me to store multiple ssh keysets for different accounts!

But, I still have this first account I created keys for without the Accounts plugin(in the default location). The owner asked me to update, and while I can still push to heroku, it won't allow me to run any rake commands, as it's asking me to use --account accountname while using those commands. There is no account name, it's just default...

Is there a way to temporarily disable Heroku accounts, so I can still access the SSH key that was created before I installed the plugin!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find the plugin in ~/.heroku/plugins - you could move it out, do what you need to do and then move it back

Comment: Ahhh! Greatly appreciated.